# extra padding on the right of parent division

Tags: css, html

I wrote some pure css, html codes that inside a div which is 80% of the screen width, I put 3 other boxes in one row which are 30% of parent width. 
**BUT There is an extra of padding on the right of of parent div that I couldnt handle so far.**
Can somebody give me a hint to remove it, please?

here is it's photo
[image]

and the following are the codes.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
   <title>CSS practice</title>
   <style>
         *{
           margin: 0;
           padding: 0;
          }
         body {
               background-color: grey;
              }
         .main {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0 auto;
                width: 80%;
                background-color: #AAA;
                }
         .container {
                    display: inline-block;
                    width: 30%;
                    height: 30%;
                    margin: 1%;
                    background-color: white;
                    text-align: center;
                    }
   </style>
   </head>
   <body>
         <div class="main">
                           <span class="container">X</span>
                           <span class="container">X</span>
                           <span class="container">X</span>
                           <span class="container">X</span>
                           <span class="container">X</span>
                           <span class="container">X</span>
         </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: extra padding? you're sure? I dont see that! https://jsfiddle.net/eylay/v2x3Lwej/3/

Comment: @AliSeyfi. See the right side if lighter grey box, please. That's not margin I guess. As you can see the distance of white boxes on the right it less than distance of light boxes on the left from the parent border.

Answer (score 2):

The width plus left and right margins of your `.container` elements didn't add up to 100% so there was extra space.  I added some comments in the code below.

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: grey;
}
.main {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #AAA;
}
/* clearfix to keep container from collapsing when floating child elements */
.main:before,
.main:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.container {
  /*display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;*/
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% / 3 - 2%); /* divide by number of columns and subtract the left and right margins */
  height: 30%;
  margin: 1%;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <span class="container">X</span>
  <span class="container">X</span>
  <span class="container">X</span>
  <span class="container">X</span>
  <span class="container">X</span>
  <span class="container">X</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add `text-align:center` to the `.main` class too.
When you add `text-align:center` to the `.container`, only X goes center but if you want to put boxes in center you should add `text-align:center` to the parent div.

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/eylay/v2x3Lwej/4/)

Comment: @Seyfi : Yes exactly (Areh, merci)